# Is The Pale Woman ever mentioned in the Farseer trilogy?

Tags: realm-of-the-elderlings

I haven't read the Farseer trilogy in quite some time, but I recently read the Tawny Man trilogy.

> In the Tawny man, The Pale Woman is described as another White Prophet, and behind the outislander trouble that the Six Duchies faced during the Farseer trilogy.

However, I can't remember reading about her in the Farseer trilogy. So was she mentioned at all in the Farseer trilogy or was she just thought of later by the author?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She is mentioned in the introduction of chapter twenty of *Royal Assassin*:

> They whisper, too, of a pale woman whom even Kebal Rawbread fears and reveres.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Were you rereading the book, or had you actually remembered it?

Comment: I've read that trilogy more times than I can remember so I knew it was there and which book it was in, but it took a good 20 minutes to find what I was looking for :)

Comment: I love it too, but the last time I read it, I was depressed for a week. So I don't read it too often. I was actually on chapter 19 of *Royal Assassin* when I saw your answer.

Comment: I know what you mean... very bittersweet, more bitter than sweet. But brilliantly told.